# Is this possible with regular expression?

Tags: java

`()` `[]` `{}` these are valid matches but `({)}` is false, eg.:

```
() - true
()[]- true
()[]{} - ture
([]) - false
(){[}] - false.
```

Can I use regular expression to compute this?

Comment: Use a stack.  It'll make your head hurt much less.

Comment: You asked an almost identical question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113504/java-best-way-to-implement-this-code

Comment: What a strangely positioned question, did you hear someone say that regex cannot be used to balance parenthesis?

Comment: @peter.murray.rust:  I don't see a duplication.  That was more broad than this question (which is still broad, mind you).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)

Comment: @Makoto: Nevermind that they are by the same user :/

Comment: @mellamokb:  "Best way" vs. "Is this possible with...".  That's what I was looking at.

Comment: No, you're going to want to look in to `Context-free grammars` and `deterministic pushdown automata`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Well-formed_nested_parentheses_and_square_brackets

Comment: @peter.murray.rust yeah but do you have a clue ???

Answer (score 5):

No, one of known limitations of regular expressions is that it can't tell whether parentheses are well formed.